# Are UTM tracking codes infallible? Does GA capture all traffic to that link?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

Does a url with UTM variables allow Google Analytics to capture all traffic that clicked on that link?

We pay an advertiser to display content of ours on their website. In this content is a link to our contact page with the necessary UTM paramaters. The advertiser says 394 people clicked on our link in March. GA recorded 6 sessions and 4 unique users.

The UTM url works and records data successfully. What I am hoping to learn is whether I can trust that the data I see in GA is accurate. Accurate enough to accuse the advertiser of fraud.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google analytics tracking and is not programing related

Comment: My first post on StackOverflow so you will have to forgive me if I didn't know how... diligent you would be in, well never mind. No one forced you to read and respond grumpy.

Comment: Welcome to stack then you might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Technically speaking I didn't respond that's an auto message you get when someone votes your question be closed :)

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/  try asking here.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will do so.